# Excel - How to SUM the results of LEFT?

Tags: excel

[image]

In row 2, I used `=LEFT(B1,(FIND("/",B1,1)-1))` to get the `288` and ‭‭‭‭`233`‬‬‬‬. But when I tried to `=SUM(B2:C2)`, it returned a 0. How do I SUM the results of `LEFT()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `LEFT()` function then it returns result as string (not as number). So, you can not sum string. You need to convert string to number. You can use below formula

```
=LEFT(B1,(FIND("/",B1,1)-1))*1
```

Or use

```
=--LEFT(B1,(FIND("/",B1,1)-1))
```

Then sum output.

You can directly sum lefts before `/` by following formula.

```
=SUM(--LEFT(B1:C1,SEARCH("/",B1:C1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: You may need to enter this formula `=SUM(--LEFT(B1:C1,SEARCH("/",B1:C1)-1))` as array entry confirm with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! But when I use the `*1`, `--` ones or the directly sum method, they all return `#VALUE!`.

Comment: @HKO2006 What is your excel version? If it is not `Office 365` then did you enter by `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`?

Comment: It's 2016. I tried with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, it adds `{` and `}` at both ends but it's still `#VALUE!`

Comment: @HKO2006 `{ }` is okay. I tested to `Excel2013` and working fine! Can you check your data in cell is there any extra characters.

Comment: Just tried with the online version of 365, they are still `#VALUE!`.

Comment: Can you please share a sample workbook via google drive or onedrive. It must work.

Comment: I copied the numbers from my browser (Brave) and your methods don't work on them but if I type the numbers out they work.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsXt8Y9aVAn3GA7MPXy3hOeQtoKqtHPw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Turns out the numbers copied from web do contain extra characters, in front of and behind `/`. It looks they are not there but I can backspace to remove them. Like this one ‭‭‭‭162‬‬‬‬/‭‭‭‭2300

Comment: Yes when you are coping from web then there are some extra invisible characters and those are cause to get error. Unless formula is okay.

Answer (score 0):

force the 288/233 to a number. the easiest way is `=LEFT(B1,(FIND("/",B1,1)-1))+0`